# change "data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values) " to python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, urllib2, urllib

every one,,I have to change some code from python 3.* to 2.7,,,however,,I just do not know what is the code `data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)` in python 2.7

> python3.*

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request


def sendsms(phonenumber,textcontent):
    url = 'http://urls?'
    values = {'username' : 'hello',
              'password' : 'world',
              'dstaddr' : phonenumber ,
              'smbody': textcontent
               }

    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
    data = data.encode('Big5') 
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, data)
    with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
       the_page = response.read()
```

> python 2.7

```
from urlparse import urlparse
from urllib2 import urlopen
from urllib import urlencode

def sendsms(phonenumber,textcontent):
    url = 'http://urls?'
    values = {'username' : 'hello',
              'password' : 'world',
              'dstaddr' : phonenumber ,
              'smbody': textcontent
               }

    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)  #python 3.* code, what about python 2.7 ?

    data = data.encode('Big5') 
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, data)
    with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
       the_page = response.read()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the equivalent for the `urllib` function calls in python 2.7, which should work.

```
import urllib
import urllib2
from contextlib import closing

def sendsms(phonenumber,textcontent):
    url = 'http://urls?'
    values = {'username' : 'hello',
              'password' : 'world',
              'dstaddr' : phonenumber ,
              'smbody': textcontent
               }

    data = urllib.urlencode(values)
    data = data.encode('Big5')
    req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
    with closing(urllib2.urlopen(req)) as response:
       the_page = response.read()
```

Edit : Thanks @Cc L for pointing the error on using `with ... as` with `urlopen` due to context manager not being implemented. Here is an alternate method where context manager returned with `closing` closes `the_page` on completion of block.

Comment: thanks for your answer,,your code is mostly correct,and I think " with urllib2.urlopen(req) as response:
       the_page = response.read()" has to change to "response = urllib2.urlopen(req)",,,otherwise it will get error "AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no attribute '__exit__' "

Answer (score 0):

first ,thanks for wolfsgang's answer in above,then I changed my code,it can work

```
import urllib
import urllib2


def sendsms(phonenumber,textcontent):
    url = 'http://urls?'
    values = {'username' : 'hello',
              'password' : 'world',
              'dstaddr' : phonenumber ,
              'smbody': textcontent
               }


    data = urllib.urlencode(values)
    data = data.encode('Big5')
    req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```